# Post Multiple Data from View to Controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to post quantity property to Controller (It's an edit action). I'm editing OrderedProductSet which is connected with ProductSet  in my SQL Database (I get the name and price from there). How to pass multiple data from the view to controller? How to write method in controller class to receive the data (I'm asking about method arguments in this specific case).

My view:

```
@model Shop.Models.ProductViewModel@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edycja zamówienia";
 }

<h2>Edycja zamówienie</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <b>Nazwa produktu</b>
        </th>
        <th>
            <b>Cena</b>
        </th>
        <th>
            <b>Ilość</b>
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.orderedProductSet)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProduktSet.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProduktSet.price)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>


<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Potwierdź zmiany" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
</div>
}



<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Powrót", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My model (in separated classes of course):

```
 public class ProductViewModel
{
     public OrderSet orderSet { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<OrderedProductSet> orderedProduktSet { get; set; }
}


public partial class OrderedProduktSet
{
    public int orderNumber{ get; set; }
    public int productNumber { get; set; }
    public int ilosc { get; set; }

    public virtual ProduktSet ProduktSet { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderSet OrderSet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should change the wording of your question.  Technically, views *never* send data to a controller (in this fashion).  It should probably ready `how do I post multiple data points to a controller method`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct controls for you collection in a `for` loop or use a custum `EditorTemplate` for `OrderedProduktSet` so that the controls are correctly named with indexers and can be bound on post back. Note the `for` loop approach required that the collection be `IList`.

```
@model Shop.Models.ProductViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.orderedProductSet.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.orderedProductSet[i].ProduktSet.name)
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.orderedProductSet[i].quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Controller (the model will be bound, including the collection of `OrderedProductSet`)

```
public ActionResult Edit(ProductViewModel model)
{
  ....
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an `EditorTemplate`

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/OrderedProduktSet.cshtml

```
@model OrderedProduktSet
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProduktSet.name)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

and in the main view

```
@model Shop.Models.ProductViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.orderedProductSet)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Second option works like a charm! Using EditorTemplates all the time now.

Answer (score -1):

Viewbag is your friend here. You normally pass data from View to Controller in MVC. You can access data set in a Viewbag in the controller in your View.

The simplest way to let your controller handle your view is to create an actionresult method in your controller with the same name as your view.

For example, your view is called Index, thus you would have the following method in your controller to handle the view data:

```
public ActionResult Index()    
{
    return View();
}
```

Accessing a list:

Use a Viewbag.

Controller

```
Viewbag.MyList = myList
```

View

```
@foreach (var item in Viewbag.MyList)
```

Here is good link for more info:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-view

Comment: i know that I should use ActionResult method. But what will be my method arguments in this specific case? I thought about `public ActionResult Edit(IENumberable<OrderedProductSet> list)` but `list` is null then. Can I really pass all the data using Viewbag only? It's not a one value, these are multiple values to pass.

Comment: I already gave you the answer above  - cheers for voting me down. Not. Use a Viewbag. Viewbag.List = MyList (in your controller) then, @foreach var item in Viewbag.MyList in your view

Comment: OP did not downvote, I did. This has nothing to do with the issue (_How to write method in controller class to receive the data_) and is bad code. OP already has a model with a collection. What would be the point of then assigning it to ViewBag?. If you did, it could not be bound to the model on post back. And you cant use a `foreach` loop for binding anyway - it doe not name the controls correctly with indexers!). And `ViewBag` is never your friend!